HTML Canvas takes too long to repaint
I'm working on a game with JavaScript using Electron.js. I'm using the HTML <canvas> element with 2d context as renderer. At some point, I've noticed that the game runs quite slow (less than 30 FPS).
Every frame, a piece of code is run by requestAnimationFrame(). I ran it through a profiler and it showed that my code is fine (takes around 2ms per frame) and that page repaints take much longer than I would expect (sometimes it's more than 30ms per paint).

Since the game renderer is too complex, I can't provide a full example, but here's a bit of my code:
// Set up the canvas
let r = document.getElementById("render");
let ctx = r.getContext("2d", {
    alpha:0,
    willReadFrequently:true
});

// Set up offscreen canvas
let offR = new OffscreenCanvas(1920, 1080);
let offCtx = offR.getContext("2d", {
    willReadFrequently: true
});

// Set canvas size
r.width = 1920;
r.height = 1080;

function drawVoxes() {
    for(let vx of voxes) {
        // If not empty, draw its texture
        if(vx.value != 0) {
            offCtx.drawImage( dataobj.textures.tiles[vx.value - 1], vx.rX, vx.rY, vx.width, vx.height );
        }
    }
}

function renderFrame() {
    // fpsTicker.tick();

    // Clear canvases
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, r.width, r.height);
    offCtx.clearRect(0, 0, r.width, r.height);

    // Draw background
    ctx.drawImage(buf, 0, 0);

    // Draw grid
    drawVoxes();

    // Apply to the main canvas
    ctx.drawImage(offR, 0, 0);
    
    // Set up for the next frame
    requestAnimationFrame(renderFrame);
}

requestAnimationFrame(renderFrame);


buf is an OffscreenCanvas object,
voxes is an array of custom helper objects,
dataobj is an object that stores all the map data.

I hope this example is enough for you to understand.
Why is this happening? Is it normal? And what can I do to lower the paint times?

EDIT: The only element on-screen is that single <canvas> for rendering.

There is probably a bug somewhere. To rule it out, please share details of the animation code by way of a Minimal reproducible example.

@traktor I added it to the question

Using the context option willReadFrequently in canvas.getContext("2d", {willReadFrequently: true}) effectively turns off hardware acceleration for that canvas.. Only use the setting if you are reading pixel data frequently IE calling ctx.getImageData and only if its causing a slowdown. I don't see any reason for you to use that setting. remove it and let the GPU handle the compositing (compositing is the green Paint task)

I second Blindman67's comment, you want hardware acceleration for these contexts, don't set the willReadFrequently if you never read its content. Now, what are the tiles sources? What size of bitmaps do they represent? Are thewidth or height properties of your vx objects variables? Otherwise you could probably win a bunch by storing them as already resized ImageBitmap objects instead of resizing these every frame.

@Kaiido the textures are all 8x8 images as Image objects. And they are resized to 120x120.

Disabling the willReadFrequently canvas context flag fixed the issue and paints do not take 30ms anymore.
